# You do not appear to have libc header files installed on your system. Please install your distribution's libc development package

Tags: nvidia, package-management, cuda

After download the latest Cuda from here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
, I tried to install it and each time I got error I fixed it.
Last error I wasn't able to fix:

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Thu Sep 30 19:16:25 2021
installer version: 470.57.02

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer
    --ui=none
    --no-questions
    --accept-license
    --disable-nouveau
    --no-cc-version-check
    --install-libglvnd

Using built-in stream user interface
-> Detected 16 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 16.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 470.57.02.
WARNING: One or more modprobe configuration files to disable Nouveau are already present at: /usr/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf, /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf.  Please be sure you have rebooted your system since these files were written.  If you have rebooted, then Nouveau may be enabled for other reasons, such as being included in the system initial ramdisk or in your X configuration file.  Please consult the NVIDIA driver README and your Linux distribution's documentation for details on how to correctly disable the Nouveau kernel driver.
-> For some distributions, Nouveau can be disabled by adding a file in the modprobe configuration directory.  Would you like nvidia-installer to attempt to create this modprobe file for you? (Answer: Yes)
-> One or more modprobe configuration files to disable Nouveau have been written.  For some distributions, this may be sufficient to disable Nouveau; other distributions may require modification of the initial ramdisk.  Please reboot your system and attempt NVIDIA driver installation again.  Note if you later wish to re-enable Nouveau, you will need to delete these files: /usr/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf, /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf
ERROR: You do not appear to have libc header files installed on your system.  Please install your distribution's libc development package.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

After reading some in the forum I found the solution is to run this command: `sudo apt-get install libc-dev libc6-dev`
And got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libc6-dev' instead of 'libc-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I was thinking it's already installed, but seem this command return nothing: `dpkg-query -l | grep libc.*dev`
What else can I do ?

The server is using AMD CPU: 48 CPUs x AMD EPYC 7402 24-Core Processor & A100 GPU

Comment: The message says "You have held broken packages". Did you mark any packages as held?

Comment: No, I didn't. This is a brand new OS.